# Ruby Watir-webdriver getting link from specific table row

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to access a link from a specif row based on a basic text/regex

Example,  I want to click on the link in the row where 2nd column text is "Cash Balances - Daily" the 3rd column will be the date am looking for "09-Sep-2013" and the link to click is in the 6th column.  [image: table screen shot]

```
<tbody> 
  <tr> 
    <td>498488.txt</td>
    <td>Cash Balances - Daily</td>
    <td>10 Sep-2013</span> </td>
    <td>No </td>
    <td class="Table_DataCelllast"> 
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_dtgrdListFiles_ctl02_lnkViewfile" onclick="javascript:dw('DownloadFilesView.aspx?DocFileID=9187191&amp;DocFileType=.txt','','menubar=yes,scrollbars,resizable,status,location','525','700');  return false;">View File</a>
    </td>
  </tr>`
```

This is what I have tried just to get the links to print out

`b.table.trs.each do |tr|
  p tr.a.link
end`

but all I get returned is this

```
#<Watir::Anchor:0x1017df620 located=false selector={:tag_name=>"a"}>
#<Watir::Anchor:0x1017df300 located=false selector={:tag_name=>"a"}>
#<Watir::Anchor:0x1017defe0 located=false selector={:tag_name=>"a"}>
#<Watir::Anchor:0x1017decc0 located=false selector={:tag_name=>"a"}>
#<Watir::Anchor:0x1017de978 located=false selector={:tag_name=>"a"}>
#<Watir::Anchor:0x1017de608 located=false selector={:tag_name=>"a"}>
#<Watir::Anchor:0x1017de2e8 located=false selector={:tag_name=>"a"}>
#<Watir::Anchor:0x1017ddfc8 located=false selector={:tag_name=>"a"}>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: why not giving the line of the page on which you want to work? Remove the html body from here,and give the link. And specifically tell what you want to do. Make it a good presentable question.

Comment: I cannot give the link because it is a private secure page.  I cannot share the credentials.

Comment: Confused what this question is on hold.

Comment: I still do not understand why this is on hold or off-topic. Can someone please explain?  Thanks!

Comment: I'll answer your question in a general way:
1) Identify your target row. E.g., with a regex that looks for
matching text in it.
2) Once you've identified your target row, you can click its link.

So your Watir code for clicking the correct View File link would look like this: `@browser.table.row(text: /#{your_target_string}/).link(text: "View File").click`

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through the rows to find the row that has the specified text. Then click the link in that row:

```
row = @browser.table.tbody.trs.find do |tr| 
    tr.td(:index => 1).text == 'Cash Balances - Daily' and
    tr.td(:index => 2).text == '09-Sep-2013'
end
row.link(:text => 'View File').click
```